# how is rosh's ok() different from rospy.is_shutdown()?

Tags: python, rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Specifically, what's the difference with how they handle a KeyboardInterrupt/SIGINT?

I would expect these two snippets to act the same, but they don't:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
r = rospy.Rate(10)
while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    print 'ok...'
    r.sleep()
```

and

```
#!/usr/bin/env rosh
r = Rate(10)
while ok():
    print "ok..."
    r.sleep()
```

The first example exits on Ctrl+C, but the second does not. What am I missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10534/how-is-rosh%27s-ok()-different-from-rospy.is_shutdown()?/) by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9115 on 2011-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most likely this is a bug in rosh. Can you file a ticket here with exact details on how you run your rosh sample?

https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/newticket

In general, rosh tries to handle SIGINT differently so that it can be used in an interactive interpreter.  rosh is not as tested when running outside of iteractive mode.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2011-07-12**:
https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3581